# Jenkins environment variables - detecting a pull request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to detect if a pull request is created on a branch.

From reading https://ci.eclipse.org/webtools/env-vars.html/

`CHANGE_TARGET` is :

```
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the target or base branch to which the change could be merged, if supported; else unset.

def isPullRequest = env.CHANGE_TARGET == 'master'
```

`isPullRequest` should resolve to true when the pull request is created and merged with master or `isPullRequest` is true when the pull request is created ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, for a multibranch pipeline project triggered by a commit in Bitbucket, we simply test the branch name :

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                if (BRANCH_NAME ==~ /PR-.*/)) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very late after MorganGeek's answer, but I had the same question and it seems (I don't know if it's available in every Jenkins version) that we can test for the existence of the variable `CHANGE_ID`.

Which could result in something very similar, but maybe a little more elegant:

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                if (CHANGE_ID) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(not sure though if it needs `env.CHANGE_ID` instead of `CHANGE_ID`